# GitHub Pages project site is at the domain root when configuring custom domain?

Tags: github-pages

GitHub Pages for project site ([not user or organization site](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites)) is available at `<username>.github.io/repo-name`.

When configuring custom domain `www.example.com` to the project site, which url is correct for the GitHub pages, `www.example.com` or `www.example.com/repo-name`?

This is not mentioned in [GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site).

Comment: The latter. Your custom domain replaces `<account>.github.io`, you can have many Pages sites within that.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested by myself.
I have made repository https://github.com/noymer/test-github-pages and
configure the custom domain https://noymer.tk to this repository.

The appropriate url is
https://noymer.tk , not https://noymer.tk/test-github-pages

[image]